# Is there a way to create a central program that can handle the different RGB components of my computer?

Tags: c++, rgb

I'm still young but I've been learning software development for about 5 years now and I wanted to write a program that was actually useful to me. I wanted to create a program (preferably in c++ but I would be willing to learn something else if I needed to) that could change the colors of all the RGB components of my computer (light strips, mouse, keyboard, RAM, etc.) without having to open up each individual program and do it manually. I was wondering if there was a way to make one custom, central program that can send requests for color changes to all the components with just one click? Or do all of the company-released software have special access to the drivers that control each device?

Perhaps this would require the reverse engineering of each program to find out their methods for sending data to each device? If so, how would I do this?

If it helps, I'm on windows 10 and my components are:

-NZXT Hue+

-Razer Cynosa Chroma Keyboard

-Redragon M711 Mouse

-G Skill Trident Z Ram

Comment: If you work hard enough at it, absolutely. But that depends on many things, like for instance what devices you have and want to work with, your operating system, etc.

Comment: For each device you want to control, check if they have a developers guide or API. If not just google forums or github and see if anyone has figured it out. Unfortunately there's not going to be a unified easy solution for this.

Comment: In windows that is highly unlikely, not all programs adhere to any particular global standard, it is fully possible and quite common for a programmer to do his own style regardless of what the rest of the windows programs use as style. If windows were a new operating system and all programs running would use a similar framework then your approach would work.

Comment: There is no common settings registry for these. There isn't even a common software system (OS) let alone common hardware. Suggestion: Try to control just one of your devices' lighting with a self-written program as a first step. BTW: I'm not really sure your question is off-topic here but it doesn't really fit. However, in any case, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: This is an ambitious project (considering the fact that you probably have to dive deep into H/W and low-level driver stuff to accomplish this - if possible at all). If low-level programming is the primary skill you want to learn then it might be a reasonable project. However, I'm afraid that this will be that time consuming that your H/W is already aged at the time you might have accomplished this. So, you may end up with a code for your H/W which you don't like to use anymore but replaced it with something new... (But certainly, you may have learnt a lot what you can apply to other projects.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe they need special access, maybe don't. I don't think there are any, but check if your company released open-source drivers. Keep in your mind that reverse engineering is usually license violation, and you should *definitely* not give the final program to anyone. For reverse engineering: first check that they are native, or .NET-based. In the second situation, it's much easier to reverse-engineer with tools like dotPeek. However, if they are native, then you should have some knowledge in assembly language, and use a disassembler. Also, check if the community created open-source drivers for them; for example, `liquidctl` is a cross-platform, open-source driver for many NZXT devices like the Smart Device, or the Kraken series.

Comment: I looked into liquidctl and it seems like exactly what I would be looking for, and if it works for the Hue+ light strips then that would be a perfect place to start. I've been wanting to learn more about software-to-hardware communication and how drivers work and I think this is the right path to follow. Thank you!